# Oracle ADF Table Row Selection Performance Tuning?

Tags: performance, oracle-adf, query-performance

I have a problem with an ADF table component in my jspx page. 
In my table each row contains 2 LOV component (seleconechoice).Table row selection value is "single".  After clicking the row table activates editing the current row after 5 seconds or more times. This table is the most used component in my page. Information entance is provided by this component. So i need to improve performance of this component.

I try some of the techniques above but can't find a solution yet.

- Viewobject tuning
- Iterator range size and fetch size is equivalent
- table content delivery  = "immediate" ... so on.

  In page definition iterator range size ="50"
  table fetchSize="50"

This table is the detail table of another view object in my page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to profile your apps to understand which part of your code causing it.
Try to reduce number of max rows retrieved from database.
Example: VO -> general -> tuning -> only up to row number 10